# Editing date list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where index is dates. I want to get the list of dates in the index but only every 90 days. So it would be `[1999-01-01, 1999-04-01, 1999-07-01...]` and so on.

```
df #is my dataframe
date_list = df.index.tolist()
new_list=[]
for date in date_list:
    new_date = date +datetime.timedelta(days=90)
    new_list.append(new_date)
```

This just gives me all the dates, but moved by 90 days. I am using `datetime.timedelta()` because my dataframe is missing dates like holidays or weekends so I can't just call every 90th cell from the dataframe.

First I just want to get the list, after that I will make a while loop to make sure that the dates in the list can me moved by one to three days in case it falls on a weekend or holiday.

Comment: I think what you could do is take the first and last index result and use this as a range and pass this to `pd.date_range(start, end, freq='90D')` or similar

Comment: It is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient method would be to generate your range using your first and last values in your index using [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html#pandas.date_range):

```
pd.date_range(start, end, freq='90D')
```

where start and end are `df.index[0]` and `df.index[-1]` respectively, the `freq` param accepts a frequency value which here is 90 days which suits your requirements.

This will be much faster than adding 90 days to every value and then scrapping the majority of them.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have a list of dates, can't you just use a stride?

```
date_list = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=365)

>>> date_list[::90]
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01', '2015-04-01', '2015-06-30', '2015-09-28',
               '2015-12-27'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='90D', tz=None)
```

Given that the dates are in your index, you can simply do:

```
new_dates = df.index[::90]
```

**EDIT**

Given that your initial dates have weekends and holidays and that you want your intervals to be 90 actual days, you can use `asof` to get the most recent value as of the 90th day interval:

```
# An index based on M-F weekdays.
weekdays = pd.Index([d for d in pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=365) 
                     if d.weekday() < 5])

new_dates = [weekdays.asof(d) for d in pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq='90D')]
>>> new_dates
[Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-04-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-06-30 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-09-28 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-12-25 00:00:00')]
```

Comment: that won't work as the OP has missing dates in their index, they want a regular stepped range which is why I proposed using `date_range`

Answer (score 1):

To improve EdChum answer:

Cause your dataframe missing dates, all dates in

```
pd.data_range(start, end, freq='90D')
```

are not necessary in your index, so you should:

```
dates_series = df.index

lst_dates = []
for dates_90D in pd.data_range(start, end, freq='90D'):
    dates_in_index = dates_series[dates_series>=dates_90D].min()
    lst_dates.append(dates_in_index)
```

same as:

```
lst_dates = [df.index[df.index>=dates_90D] for dates_90D in pd.data_range(start, end, freq='90D')]
```

Comment: great answer, but it would just skip the date that is not in the original index. I am better of getting a separate list of dates like `pd.data_range(start, end, freq='90D')`, and set up a function that will add a couple of days to a given date  if it is missing in the original index. At the end I will get a date every 90 to 95 days